# Why when I try to connect on my laravel app, its always the last entry in base that get connected?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

First of all I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I'm new to this framework.
Well, I'm trying to make a connection page with laravel, I did this :

```
$isValid = LdapReader::logExist($request->only(['identifiant_usine', 'password']));
  
if($isValid){
    
    $user = User::where('identifiant_usine', $request->only(['identifiant_usine']))->get()->first();
      
    if($user !== null){

            Auth::login($user);
        
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }
        else{
            Session::flash('flash_message', "L'utilisateur existe mais n'a pas la permission de se connecter à l'application");
            Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-danger');

            return redirect(route('login'));
        }
```

Everything's ok with my LDAP, I've got the right user to log.
If I add `dd($user)` after the `Auth::login($user)` or `dd(Auth::user())` I've got the right user to log but after the redirection in my navbar the username isn't the good one...
It's always the last one that get entered in the base.

Did someone already got this problem before ?

UPDATE
Here's my navbar

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->nom }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>
                                @if(Auth::user()->role === 1)
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}">
                                        {{ __('Enregistrer un compte') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

I've just install debugbar and it looks like that in my controller :

> $request->only(['identifiant_usine'])

output 0 instead of the correct value

UPDATE
I found where the problem was : My primary key in my table user is typped as varchar, in my model I've forgot to specify it so I've to add `public $incrementing = false;`
Now my model isn't trying to convert a varchar into an increment..

Comment: Can you update your answer with navbar template?

Comment: Ok, if you says that `$request->only(['identifiant_usine'])` gets you incorrect value, you need to check why it happens for correct work your code.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov Yup I just checked with debugbar and the query I've got is `select * from `users` where `identifiant_usine` = 0 limit 1` so I think the problem come from `$request->only(['identifiant_usine'])` I'll check that

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov I've just try some things and even if I remplace `$request->only(['identifiant_usine'])` by the value I want, I've still got the querry  `select * from users where identifiant_usine = 0 limit 1`

Comment: So, where does `identifiant_usine` come from? You need to check you client side.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov I've tried a `dd($request->only(['identifiant_usine']))` and I've got the value I've entered in the input, I really don't know where the problem can be...